# How do I parse a String into an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have a string (example below) that I would like to parse into an array

`//just a stupid example
String s = "Mary Mark {John Brown} Honey lollipop Badger {Oh My God} {Such stupid}";`

I'm interested in breaking that string to String[][] or ArrayList, so if i called:

`String[][] x = transform(s);`

x would contain something like this:

`String[][] x = {{"Mary"}, {"Mark"}, {"John", "Brown"}, {"Honey"}, {"lollipop"}, {"Badger"}, {"Oh", "My", "God"}, {"Such", "stupid"}};`

how do i do that?

EDIT: changed to 2d array

Comment: is `{"Such", "stupid"}` one string?

Comment: but X has only 1 dimension

Comment: You claim that you want **one dimensional** array of String, but your output contains `{"John", "Brown"}` which is not surrounded by `"` so it doesn't look like one string, but inner array of string. So what is `{"John", "Brown"}` exactly, string or array of strings? Also your example lacks last `}` after `{"Such", "stupid"}`.

Comment: nope. subarray with two strings

Comment: maybe what you actually want is String[][] x = {{"Mary"}, {"Mark"}, {"John", "Brown"}, {"Honey"}, {"lollipop"}, {"Badger"}, {"Oh", "My", "God"}, {"Such", "stupid"}}; ?

Comment: that could acctually work. but how do i make that? :/

Comment: I'm currently thinking: start with `split("}");` then a `split("{");` then loop through for everything that `startsWith("{");` and `endsWith("}");` and turning those into subarrays...I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: So you are saying that you want array which can also contain arrays. So let me ask you another question, can your string you want to split have more nested `{}` like for instance `"foo {bar {baz}}"`? If yes then what should be result of transforming it?

Comment: @Pshemo nope. 2d max.

Comment: @MarijanSmetko If you want to a String[][], edit your question and say it clear.

Comment: It's not possible to have a 2D array in which elements have different size.

Comment: My answer does not contain a full code listing, but gives you everything you need to build the two dimensional array.  Basically it's like wns349's answer and then split each match by space to turn each matching string into an array of one or more strings.

Comment: @herman What would be the size of the array `String[][] x` be? It would have 8 elements for the groups of words, but groups have different size? (some are 3, some are 1). Unless you explicitly know the maximum size of the group of words (in that example, it's 3 max for `Oh My God`), it doesn't seem to be possible. Even if so, it would be inefficient.

Comment: You don't need to know any maximum size. The 2D array doesn't have a single size of its own.  The 'outer' array would have 8 elements.  Each of those 'inner' arrays would have it's own size.

Comment: @herman, Yap, now that I think of it, you are right. I was mistaken for a while there, sorry! Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: Thanks for the effort of all of you, but i realised that i could simply change my file into:

Mary\n 
Mark\n 
John Brown\n 
and so on...
.
.
.

it's easier to code and much more efficient. i'm sry this not-properly-planned action in my project took your time.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you may be looking for something like

```
String s = "Mary Mark {John Brown} Honey lollipop Badger {Oh My God} {Such stupid}";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\{)[^{}]+(?=\\})|\\w+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
List<String[]> tokens = new ArrayList<String[]>();
while (m.find()) {
    tokens.add(m.group().split("\\s+"));
}

String[][] result = tokens.toArray(new String[tokens.size()][]);

// lets see if it works as planned
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
```

Output:

```
[[Mary], [Mark], [John, Brown], [Honey], [lollipop], [Badger], [Oh, My, God], [Such, stupid]]
```

Explanation:

`"(?<=\\{)[^{}]+(?=\\})|\\w+"` is regular expression which searches for

- `(?<=\\{)[^{}]+(?=\\})` characters which are not `{` nor `}` and are between `{` and `}` (these brackets will not be included). `(?<=...)` and `(?=...)` are part of [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanism
- or `\\w+` one or more alphanumeric characters

After they will find all such tokens they will split them on any kind of one or more whitespace `\\s+` to create separate array of strings so

- `"foo".split("\\s+")` will become array `["foo"]`
- `"foo bar".split("\\s+")` will become array `["foo", "bar"]`

Next I convert list of such arrays into two dimensional list using `toArray` method.

Comment: That regex is hardcore. This is a beautiful solution, even though I can't really wrap my head around it. Any tips on how to learn this complexity of regexes? I'm curious, that is all.

Comment: @Zhuinden Regex is not that complicated when you will learn its syntax and mechanisms. Best place I know is tutorial at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ but if you want to learn how to use regex in Java you can start at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/. Also [documentation of `Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing substring containing {} brackets should be regarded as one?

I suggest you to use regex to parse the given string. I am not very friendly with regex myself, but something like below might be able to help you:

```
String s = "Mary Mark {John Brown} Honey lollipop Badger {Oh My God} {Such stupid}";
String p = "\\{[A-Za-z ]*\\}|\\w+";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

then expected output is:

```
Mary
Mark
{John Brown}
Honey
lollipop
Badger
{Oh My God}
{Such stupid}
```

Comment: sry, but no. inside `{}` there are seperate strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that is most likely not efficient, but it works, it's based on a lot of string manipulation and truncating parts off the string:

```
public class StringSplitter
{
    public static String[] transform(String string)
    {
        String[] splitString = string.split(" ");
        List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i = 0;
        while(i < splitString.length)
        {
            if(!splitString[i].startsWith("{"))
            {
                listOfStrings.add(splitString[i]);
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                boolean concatEnd = false;
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                splitString[i] = splitString[i].substring(1);
                sb.append(splitString[i]);
                i++;
                while(!concatEnd) 
                {
                    if(!splitString[i].endsWith("}"))
                    {
                        sb.append(" " + splitString[i]);
                        i++;
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        splitString[i] = splitString[i].substring(0, splitString[i].length()-1);
                        sb.append(" " + splitString[i]);
                        concatEnd = true;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                listOfStrings.add(sb.toString());
            }
        }
        return listOfStrings.toArray(new String[listOfStrings.size()]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "Mary Mark {John Brown} Honey lollipop Badger {Oh My God} {Such stupid}";
        for(String string : transform(s)) 
        {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Mary
Mark
John Brown
Honey
lollipop
Badger
Oh My God
Such stupid
```

Comment: works, but my input, the `String x` should be the same as in question.

Comment: done and fixed for new input, although it *is* a one dimensional array at the moment as it was initially said it was meant to be...

Comment: Please note that the code would break if the strings contain `{` or `}` apart from being group indicators, like `"I like {apples}"` would break it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Pattern.compile("\\{[A-Za-z ]*\\}|\\w+")
```

to build a regex pattern.

Then call

```
pattern.matcher(input)
```

to get a matcher for the input string.

Then iterate over the resulting matches using

```
matcher.find()
```

For each match, add the output of

```
match.split("\\s+")
```

(which gives you an array of one or more words) to an array or List.